# Trapped in the Notes field: Is there no KeePassXC "OK" keyboard shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys

When editing an entry's Notes field in KeePassXC 2.2.0, how can you hit the OK button to save the current entry and go back to the main listing, without using the mouse?

These tactics fail:

- Pressing Tab or Enter.  (Just inserts the corresponding literal, because the Notes field is multiline.)
- Pressing Ctrl+Enter.  (No effect.)
- Pressing Shift+Tab.  (This does actually work--I had misremembered--but if I have to backward-tab through a dozen fields to get to the OK button, it's hardly a shortcut.  Also I have to guess whether it's finally on OK or not, because the last 5 focuses do not cause any visual change!)
- Pressing Alt+Enter.  (Toggles Full-Screen Mode.)
- Pressing Alt+O.  (Although the O is not underlined on the OK button, I guessed at this one coming from other KeePass variants.  Here in KeePassXC all it does is insert an `o` at the cursor.)

Full debug info:

```
KeePassXC - Version 2.2.0
Revision: caa49a8ef3ee28ed478192389b21d61107b3b8e0

Libraries:
- Qt 5.5.1
- libgcrypt 1.6.5

Enabled extensions:
- KeePassHTTP
- Auto-Type
- YubiKey
```

PS I would **create a new tag for KeePassXC** (different from both KeePassX and KeePass) but I don't have enough rep.  Please feel free to do so.

Comment: Try using the tab key to select the "OK" button and hit "Enter"

Comment: @Panther thanks for your comment, I realized I left out some important details.  I've updated the question.  BTW feel free to create a KeePassXC tag for me, I see you have enough rep.  :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the OK button's `O` is underlined:

[image]

This suggests that it is a keyboard accelerator for that button, and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> works for me.

Comment: Ah, that's another thing I had tried already, but forgotten.  I'll update the question (it doesn't work.)

Comment: Mine doesn't have the underline but also doesn't have icons on the Apply/Cancel/OK buttons.  What version is this?

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer and screenshot though.  I wish it worked.